# Yii Gridview Change Column Value Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii

I'm facing a troublesome scenario for quite sometime without any clear solution to it. The problem is that i have a gridview which shows products information and return on investment for 5d, 6m, and 12m and another column called total profitable %. This total profitable % column is calculated for each months separately and is stored in separate columns in the database.

Now the thing is , how to make this column called total profitable % show the info for the roi month that the user is sorting on currently. So if the user sorts on 5d ROI column the total profitable % will recalculate to 5 days total profitable %. If the user sorts on 6m ROI column then the total profitable % will again recalculate to 6m , and so on. I've been trying to find a way to achieve this by setting the "visible" property to false for the total profitable % column for all the month except for the one that the user is sorting the ROI column on, but its not working at all.

Here is the gridview in question.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'product-news-grid-'. $id,
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'news-datagrid',
    ),
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->searchProductNewsSymbol($name, $headlines, $publish_date), 
    'filter' => $dataProvider,
    'enableHistory' => false,
    'ajaxUpdate' => 'product-news-grid-'. $id,
    'ajaxUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/productDetails/AjaxUpdateProductNews'),
    'pager' => array(
        'header' => '',
        'cssFile' => false,
        'maxButtonCount' => 5,
        'selectedPageCssClass' => 'active',
        'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
        'firstPageCssClass' => 'previous',
        'lastPageCssClass' => 'next',
        'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
        'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
        'prevPageLabel' => '<',
        'nextPageLabel' => '>',
    ),
    'summaryCssClass' => 'label label-warning',
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'header' => 'Name',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<div class="product-name"> <a target="_blank" href="'. $data->id .'" > '. $data->name .'</a></div>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'headlines',
            'header' => 'Headlines',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<div class="product-news"> <a target="_blank" href="'. $data->link .'" > '. $data->headlines .'</a></div>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'publish_date',
            'header' => 'Date',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->publish_date .'</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'fived_roi',
            'header' => '5d ROI',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->fived_roi .'</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'sixm_roi',
            'header' => '6m ROI',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->sixm_roi .'</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
          array(
            'name' => 'twlm_roi',
            'header' => '12m ROI',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->twlm_roi .'</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'fived_profit',
            'header' => 'Total Profit %',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->fived_profit .'%</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'sixm_profit',
            'header' => 'Total Profit %',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->sixm_profit .'%</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
            'visible' => false
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'twlm_profit',
            'header' => 'Total Profit %',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<span class="news-pub-date">'. $data->twlm_profit .'%</span>';
            },
            'type' => 'raw',
            'visible' => true
        ),


    )
));

?>
```

I tried to make this work by attaching a click handler to the table column headers , and rendering a different view which has anyone of the Total profitable % column visible. But its not working, cause the sorting doesn't work and the whole grid falls apart after rendering a different one.

So can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve the desired result. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Maxx

**EDIT**

Here is the code for searchProductNewsSymbol()

```
public function searchProductNewsSymbol ( $name ,
                                            $headlines = NULL ,
                                            $publish_date = NULL ) {

        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria ;


        $criteria->select = 'name, publish_timestamp, publish_date, headlines, link, last_updated';
        $criteria->group = 'headlines';
        $criteria->compare ( 'name' ,
                             $name ,
                             true ) ;

        if ( isset ( $headlines ) || $headlines != "" ) {
            $criteria->compare ( 'headlines' ,
                                 $headlines ,
                                 TRUE ,
                                 'AND' ) ;
        }

        if ( isset ( $publish_date ) || $publish_date != "" ) {
            $criteria->compare ( 'publish_date' ,
                                 $publish_date ,
                                 TRUE ,
                                 'AND' ) ;
        }
        return new CActiveDataProvider ( $this ,
                                         array (
                                 'criteria' => $criteria ,
                                 'sort'     => array (
                                                          'defaultOrder' => 'publish_date desc' ,
                                 ) ,
                ) ) ;
    }
```

Comment: please post the structure of database table.

Comment: check the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292784/yii-how-to-ajax-update-the-cgridview

Comment: @jailedabroad well the schema is same as the columns specified in the post

Comment: @mazraara Thanks for the link. I've tried that solution before, you know to ajax update grid on a timer. But in my case the ajax update should be triggered on column sorting.

Comment: @Maxx try this answer i posted.

Answer (score 0):

On your button click, try doing this.

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.update("<id of CGridView>");
```

Comment: Yes but this only refreshes the grid. The sorting of the column still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the code for searchProductNewsSymbol() method.

Comment: Sure check my post above